# Tabify / Beautify HTML in Texmate?

Tags: php, html, textmate

How can I "tabify" HTML in Textmate?

I've tried selecting all, and then using Cmd+option+[ but it comes out a little weird...

If it's not possible to do this in TextMate, if someone could help me write a PHP function to do it, I could potentially make my own TextMate plugin.

```
<div>                                            
 <div>
  <span>Reversal System, 1 kit</span></div>
  <div>
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
   <span>3.9</span>                         
   <p>(based on 
    <span>7</span> reviews)</p>
    <div>
     <a href="#">
      link</a>
      <div>
       <p>
        <span>Distribution</span></p>
        <div>
         <ul>
          <li>
           <p>
            <span>5 Stars</span></p>
            <div>
             <div>&nbsp;</div></div>
             <p>
              <span>(3)</span></p></li>
              <li>
               <p>
                <span>4 Stars</span></p>
                <div>
                 <div>&nbsp;</div></div>
                 <p>
                  <span>(2)</span></p></li>
                  <li>
                   <p>
                    <span>3 Stars</span></p>
                    <div>
                     <div>&nbsp;</div></div>
                     <p>
                      <span>(1)</span></p></li>
                      <li>
                       <p>
                        <span>2 Stars</span></p>
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        <p>
                         <span>(0)</span></p></li>
                         <li>
                          <p>
                           <span>1 Stars</span></p>
                           <div>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div></div>
                            <p>
                             <span>(1)</span></p></li></ul></div> </div></div></div>
                             <div></div>
                             <div>
                              <p>83%</p> 
                              <p>of respondents would recommend this to a friend.</p></div></div>
```

If I use this web page: http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier

It comes out like this:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <span>Reversal System, 1 kit</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div>
   &nbsp;
  </div>
  <span>3.9</span>
  <p>
   (based on <span>7</span> reviews)
  </p>
  <div>
   <a href="#">
   link</a>
   <div>
    <p>
     <span>Distribution</span>
    </p>
    <div>
     <ul>
      <li>
      <p>
       <span>5 Stars</span>
      </p>
      <div>
       <div>
        &nbsp;
       </div>
      </div>
      <p>
       <span>(3)</span>
      </p>
      </li>
      <li>
      <p>
       <span>4 Stars</span>
      </p>
      <div>
       <div>
        &nbsp;
       </div>
      </div>
      <p>
       <span>(2)</span>
      </p>
      </li>
      <li>
      <p>
       <span>3 Stars</span>
      </p>
      <div>
       <div>
        &nbsp;
       </div>
      </div>
      <p>
       <span>(1)</span>
      </p>
      </li>
      <li>
      <p>
       <span>2 Stars</span>
      </p>
      <div>
       &nbsp;
      </div>
      <p>
       <span>(0)</span>
      </p>
      </li>
      <li>
      <p>
       <span>1 Stars</span>
      </p>
      <div>
       <div>
        &nbsp;
       </div>
      </div>
      <p>
       <span>(1)</span>
      </p>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <p>
   83%
  </p>
  <p>
   of respondents would recommend this to a friend.
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

That's a whole lot nicer. How can I make TextMate do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML bundle includes HTML Tidy (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>).  It does more than format (e.g. closing tags, fixing bad nesting), so if you want it to format-only go into Bundles > Bundle Editor > Show Bundle Editor, and duplicate/customize that command as you see fit.

- [Tidy overview](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)
- [Tidy quick reference](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html)
- [Tidy full documentation](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs)

Answer (score 0):

I came here by "googling" `textmate beautify` and cczona's answer helped, but I faced a problem by using `Bundle > HTML > Tidy` as it was **replacing** my `<!DOCTYPE html>` with different document type. I started digging into the bundle code, however I found out that there's another way to do **indention cleanup only**: All you have to do is select the text and click on `Indent Selection` under `Text` menu.

So it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> by default

*This answer is for people in 2014 and plus, using version 2 and higher of TextMate*